# Constraint Violation in spring jpa while saving entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In the processOrder method when i try saving the tacoOrder entity it gives me this error

```
jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.tacohouse.entities.Taco] during persist time for groups [jakarta.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='You must choose at least 1 ingredient', propertyPath=ingredients, rootBeanClass=class com.example.tacohouse.entities.Taco, messageTemplate='You must choose at least 1 ingredient'}
```

I set up debug logs and saw that the object coming from form binding in method parameter is perfectly fine and includes tacos with ingredients properly.

This is the processOrder method

```
    @Transactional 
    @PostMapping("/current")
    public String processOrder(@ModelAttribute("order") @Valid TacoOrder order, Errors errors,
                               @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "orderForm";
        }
        order.setUser(user);
        order.setPlacedAt(new Date());
        
        log.info(" {} ", sessionScopedTacoOrderManager.getTacoOrder()); //fine
        log.info(" {} ", order); //fine

        TacoOrder tacoOrder  = orderRepository.save(order);  //problem in this

        user.addTacoOrder(tacoOrder);
        userRepository.save(user);

        log.info("Order submitted: {}", tacoOrder);
       
        return "redirect:/orders";
    }
```

these are the subsequent logs

```
2024-03-18 19:26:01.932 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.e.t.controllers.OrderController -TacoOrder(id=94ef1789-4757-41db-8196-bf88117b498e, placedAt=Mon Mar 18 19:26:01 IST 2024, deliveryName=a, deliveryStreet=a, deliveryCity=a, deliveryState=a, deliveryZip=a, ccNumber=4417123456789113, ccExpiration=11/2024, ccCVV=111, tacos=[Taco(id=null, createdAt=Mon Mar 18 19:25:45 IST 2024, name=firstTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CHED, name=Cheddar, type=CHEESE)])])

2024-03-18 19:26:01.932 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.e.t.controllers.OrderController - TacoOrder(id=94ef1789-4757-41db-8196-bf88117b498e, placedAt=Mon Mar 18 19:26:01 IST 2024, deliveryName=a, deliveryStreet=a, deliveryCity=a, deliveryState=a, deliveryZip=a, ccNumber=4417123456789113, ccExpiration=11/2024, ccCVV=111, tacos=[Taco(id=null, createdAt=Mon Mar 18 19:25:45 IST 2024, name=firstTaco, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CHED, name=Cheddar, type=CHEESE)])])


2024-03-18 19:26:01.932 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.e.t.controllers.OrderController - Order submitted: TacoOrder(id=94ef1789-4757-41db-8196-bf88117b498e, placedAt=2024-03-18 19:26:01.908, deliveryName=a, deliveryStreet=a, deliveryCity=a, deliveryState=a, deliveryZip=a, ccNumber=4417123456789113, ccExpiration=11/2024, ccCVV=111, tacos=[Taco(id=null, createdAt=null, name=null, ingredients=[])])
```

As per the logs, the current sessional Order and order from form binding, either of them can be used and they both are correctly filled.

This is the method for processing Tacos if you need

```
@PostMapping
    public String processTaco(@Valid Taco taco,Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "designTaco";
        }
        taco.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        TacoOrder tacoOrder = sessionScopedTacoOrderManager.getTacoOrder();
        tacoOrder.addTaco(taco);
        log.info("Processing taco: {}", taco);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }
```

its logs

```
2024-03-19 15:05:19.335 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.e.t.c.DesignTacoController - Processing taco: Taco(id=null, createdAt=Tue Mar 19 15:05:19 IST 2024, name=Ansh Anand, ingredients=[Ingredient(id=CHED, name=Cheddar, type=CHEESE)])
```

These are the entities

```
@Data
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class TacoOrder{
    @Id //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private Date placedAt;
    @NotBlank(message = "Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;
    @NotBlank
    private String deliveryStreet;
    @NotBlank(message = "City is required")
    private String deliveryCity;
    @NotBlank(message = "State is required")
    private String deliveryState;
    @NotBlank(message = "Zip Code is required")
    private String deliveryZip;
    @CreditCardNumber(message = "Invalid Credit Card Number")
    private String ccNumber;
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/20(2[3-9]|[3-9][0-9])$",message = "Must be of format MM/YYYY")
    private String ccExpiration;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;
    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tacoOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Taco> tacos = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addTaco(Taco taco) {
        taco.setTacoOrder(this);
        this.tacos.add(taco);
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor //if we make a cunstructor @data wont make a noArgConstructor iteelf, so we define it
public class Taco{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date createdAt;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ingredient_ref",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_order_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private TacoOrder tacoOrder;

    public Taco(Date createdAt, String name, List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED,force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;

    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE, EXTRA
    }
}
```

Why when saving the tacoOrder, the taco list goes null? (i removed the cascading on the list of tacos to test if anything different happens, it didnt give error while saving as it did not save the taco sub entity but the TacoOrder that was saved didnt have any tacos in the tacoList field)
Why does the save() method nullifies the taco list of the TacoOrder object?

I was trying to save tacoOrder and its subsequent tacos. But when saving it was giving me validation error even though there shouldnt be such a validation error as it wasnt empty. I think the save()  method of repository is nullifying the Taco list of the Taco Order object.
The error is coming when the method tries to save tacoOrder in order Repository.
Problem is jpa is making a new taco list with null entries instead of adding the taco list currently present in TacoORder object in the database.
I cant find where it actually making it do this

This is how ingredients are being saved in case it helps: (im preloading database with ingredients using ingredientRepository before the application starts)

```
@ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model){
        Iterable<Ingredient> tempo = ingredientRepository.findAll();
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        tempo.forEach(ingredients::add);
        Ingredient.Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for(Ingredient.Type type: types){
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),filterByType(ingredients , type));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you save a child entity before adding it to the parent. For example persist taco before adding it to tacoOrder. Taco id is autogenerated on persisting and therefore could be the one causing this error.

Comment: it wont cause an issue with cascading then will it while persisting tacoOrder?

Comment: i tried what you said and yeah it worked perfectly fine. The only thing i did not understand was without saving, tacos had null @Id fields, this caused hibernate to make new Taco objects with null fields?

Comment: This is because Hibernate will try to persist the child entities when cascading the persist operation from the parent entity, but the child entities are not yet managed by the persistence context.
Try to save child entities first and change your cascade type according to your needs. E.g use `CascadeType.PERSIST` instead of `CascadeType.ALL`.
Lastly, kindly accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to debug the problem from your question. What code line throws the exception in question?

One thing you could try out: When you annotate a method with `@Transactional` you do not need to explicitly call the `repository.save()` methods. Instead just add the `TacoOrder` to the `User` and let `@Transactional` do the rest without calling any `.save()` method. However, this requires a `CascadeType.ALL` between `User` and `TacoOrder`, but this feels reasonable.

Comment: i edited the question so people can better understand it. Also i just added the @transaction as i was lazily fetching the user's orderList field after saving the order and it was giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this i just needed to add, Taco entities to the database using Taco Repository before adding them to their parent entity which is TacoOrder.
The Id field of tacos were auto incremented on save and when adding it to TacoOrder entity, the Ids were null and that was causing the error.